# Android - Reducir las funciones setOnClickListener()

Tags: android

Resulta que tengo 2 menus en pantalla, uno horizontal y otro vertical hecho con Linearlayouts, y por lo menos tengo 15 botones. Mi consulta es... ¿Hay algun patrón o alguna optimización que ustedes utilicen para no tener que realizar los setOnClickListener en onCreate()?

Por ejemplo, antes usaba un Toolbar con un menu, entonces facilmente con un item.getItemId() y un switch lo resolvía. Pero ahora tengo que uno por uno relacionar la vista con el controlador y a cada uno setear un OnCLickListener, y me parece que estoy repitiendo mucho codigo ya que en OnClick solo llamo a otra función.

Espero me puedan ayudar!
Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personalmente y aunque podría no ser la mejor opción, podrías usar una **Lista** de `Button`'s, cada identificador del botón dentro de un arreglo para crear el objeto, para después agregarlo a la lista, luego implementas la interface `View.OnClickListener` para asignar eventos específicos a ciertos id's o como mencionas llamar a una función por defecto, aquí el ejemplo:

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{ 
    private List<Button> buttons;
    private static final int[] BUTTONS = {
        R.id.button1,
        R.id.button2, 
        R.id.button3,
        R.id.button4,
        R.id.button5,
        R.id.button6
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tuview);

        buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();

        for(int id : BUTTONS) {
            Button button = (Button)findViewById(id);
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
            buttons.add(button);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        switch (view.getId())
        {
          case R.id.button1: //id's especificos
              //Tu metodo
              break;
          default:
              //Metodo por defecto
              break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, genial! Me resulto muy util! Muchisimas gracias